# Using Collection<Interface> is possible, but does it correct?

Tags: c#

The best practices are to program against the interface rather than the concrete class. I want to keep container of class that implements interface IPet. Does it correct? `List<IPet> petList = new List<IPet>();` Or it's better to create an abstract class?

```
public interface IPet
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        void Introduce();
    }
    public class Parrot : IPet
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Parrot(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

    public void Introduce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"My name is {Name}. I am a parrot");
    }
}

public class Cat : IPet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Cat(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Introduce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"My name is {Name}. I am a cat");
    }
}

  PetShop petShop = new PetShop();
  petShop.Add(new Cat("Garfield"));
  petShop.Add(new Parrot("Kesha"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using interface in generics is the good choice!

Using abstract class force you to place any type in single chain of inheritance that can cause a problem with application evolution.

Besides, if you have a repeating behavoir you can create abstract class wich implements required interface, so you'll get advantages of both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create an abstract class and put all repeating logic into it. Your classes look the same, only the `Introduce()` method is different, but you can use `this.GetType().Name.ToLower()` instead of "cat" and "parrot".

So, you can have the following:

```
public abstract class Pet : IPet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected Pet(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Introduce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"My name is {Name}. I am a {this.GetType().Name.ToLower()}");
    }
}

public class Cat : Pet
{    
    public Cat(string name)
        : base(name)
    {       
    }   
}
```